# Script needs converting to export to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I put together the below, which does the job. However, the output isn't very workable. So I wanted to output this all to a CSV using `Export-Csv`. Im aware I can do this by moving to a `ForEach-Object` query, but im not entirely sure how to achieve that.

I have added an attempt to convert it in hopes of a little help. I'm not sure how to specify the variable for each object. For example the first section calls all domains in the forest. How do i use each response in the next piped query? and so on.

```
$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains
$controllers = @()
$worked = $false

foreach ($domain in $domains) {
    $controller = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -ForceDiscover -DomainName $domain |
                  Select-Object HostName
    $controllers += $controller
}
while (-not $worked) {
    try {
        foreach ($item in $controllers) {
            $value = $item.HostName.Value
            Write-Host $value
            Write-Host 'Domain Admins'

            Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Domain Admins' -Server $value |
                Get-ADUser -Properties name, samaccountname, Description, EmailAddress |
                Where {$_.Enabled -eq $true} |
                Format-Table Name, SamAccountName, Description, EmailAddress -AutoSize
        }
        $worked = $true
    } catch {}
}
```

**Conversion Attempt**

```
ForEach-Object{ 
(Get-ADForest).domains | Get-ADDomainController -Discover -ForceDiscover -DomainName $domain |Select-Object HostName |  Get-ADGroupMember -identity 'Domain Admins' -Server $value | Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname, Description, EmailAddress | Where {$_.Enabled -eq $true} 
}| Export-Csv -Path "$HOME/Desktop/DomainAdmins.csv" samaccountname, Description, EmailAddress -AutoSize
```

Comment: Replace `Format-Table` with `Export-Csv -Append`.

Comment: also, why are you using $worked? this makes no sense.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Take a look at the third line from the bottom. The variable is used to terminate the `while` loop after the `foreach loop ran without a terminating error. A little awkward, but should work.

Comment: i know it should work, but it doesnt make any sense

Comment: @4c74356b41 It does make sense. PowerShell [interprets an empty/null variable as `$false`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/), so the loop continues until the variable is set to `$true` (or otherwis filled with a value).

Comment: god, why do you wrap foreach with while??

Comment: this script works as expected. Occasionally a dc in the forest fails comms thats why im using the worked variable.

Comment: For that it would be more sensible to put the `while` loop and `try`/`catch` around just the `Get-ADGroupMember ...` pipeline, so you don't repeat all queries just because one failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the values from your Get-ADUser call and put them in an object, you can then pipe to convertto-csv.

Here's an example:

```
$arr = @([pscustomobject]@{name="name"; sam="samaccountname"}, [pscustomobject]@{name="name2"; sam="samaccountname2"});

$arr | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
"name","sam"
"name","samaccountname"
"name2","samaccountname2"
```

You could get rid of the Format-Table call. The code I've shown in the example pipes and array of objects into the convertto-csv cmdlet. So if Get-ADUser returns objects, you should be able to pipe right into ConvertTo-CSV or Export-Csv -append

The objects are hashtables that are cast to pscustomobjects, it's a nice quick way to illustrate the technique.

The result, as shown, will be csv headers that match your hashtable keys, and the hastable values will be the CSV values.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine in my local environment and storing the result in **D:\Test_File.csv**

```
$domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains
$controllers = @()
$worked = $false
foreach ($domain in $domains) {
$controller = Get-ADDomainController -Discover -ForceDiscover -DomainName $domain | Select-Object HostName
$controllers += $controller
}
while (-not $worked) {
try 
{
  foreach ($item in $controllers)
        {
        $value = $item.HostName.Value
        Write-Host $value
        Write-Host 'Domain Admins'
        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Domain Admins' -Server $value |
             Get-ADUser -Properties name, samaccountname, Description, EmailAddress |?{$_.Enabled -eq $true}|Export-Csv -Append "D:\Test_File.csv"
        }
    #$worked = $true
}
catch 
{
$Error_Message=$_.Exception.Message
}
}
```

Comment: This partially works, im only getting the data from the Get-ADUser object, Id want all the data to go into the csv. So that would include the domain name, maybe as a coloum in the csv?

Comment: @iNoob: 
You can use **Get-ADDomain** for the domain name and you can append that in the CSV file like  "  | Export-Csv -Append "D:\Test_File.csv""
You can use `(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).Domain ` to get the current system is under which domain and you can append the same in the CSV.